# With Kinematic bodies is it better to use SetLinearVelocity or SetPosition in box2d?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

Basically the title, because I've had alot of trouble with using the SetLinearVelocity with my kinematic bodies I've decided to use SetPosition instead. In regards to triggering contact events etc. is it better to move them using SetLinearVelocity or will SetPosition be fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the kinematic body to move around and trigger sensors then you can get the same results using either SetLinearVelocity or SetPosition.

Where you **will** get different results is when your kinematic body collides with dynamic bodies. If you are driving the position manually with SetPosition then the solver obviously wont have the velocity information for the body to calculate things correctly such as friction.